# Find residues at the singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, residue-calculus, singularity

I have a function $f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{z^6}$. I have to find the singularities and the corresponding residues. I think there is a single pole at $z=0$, which has order 6.

For the residue, I did this:
$\text{Res}(f,0) = \frac{1}{5!} \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^5}{dz^5}(z^6 \cdot \frac{\cos(z)}{z^6}) = \frac{1}{5!}\lim_{z \to 0} -\sin(x) = 0$

Am I right, or am I missing something?

Comment: It is correct. I think you meant 'single pole of order $6$' when you said 'simple pole of order $6$'.

Comment: You are right! Thank you

Comment: Y ou can also use the series expansion of $\cos z$ to see that coefficient of $\frac  1 z$ in $f(z)$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, but it is much simpler to say that, since $f$ is an even function, the residue at $0$ is $0$.